# Node, how can I send response headers on a node/express app?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I have a basic server. One of my tests that I need to pass is to send the response header of 200. I added the code for the server as it is now. But not sure how to send response headers. Thanks for any help you may be able to provide!

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var Users = require('./models/users');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// YOUR CODE BELOW
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var router = express.Router();

// middleware for all requests:
router.use(function(req, res, next){
  console.log('we out here babay!');
  // get to the next route and ensures we don't stop here.
  next();
})

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.json({ message: 'hooray! welcome to our api!' });
});

app.use('/api', router);

// Do not touch this invocation of the `listen` method
app.listen('8888', function () {
  console.log('listening on 8888');
});

// Do not touch the exports object
module.exports = app;
```

Comment: The default status is 200 so any regular response will already be 200.  You can set a specific response code with `res.status(nnn)` any time before you send the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use `res.status(CODE)` method!

```
res.status(200).json({ message: 'hooray! welcome to our api!' });
```

As highlighted in comments by [**jfriend00**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/816620/jfriend00), default status code is `200` so any regular response will already be `200` but for other codes like `500` or `404`, if your client side is considering it while reading the response, you can use `res.status()` method.

Comment: No need to explicitly set 200 as that is the default.

Comment: `.post(function(req, res){
  var user = {}
  user.name = req.body.name;
  user.email = req.body.email;
  console.log('!!!!!!!!!I just ran babay!!!!!!!!!')
  var addNew = Users.addOne(user)
  res.status(201).json(addNew);
})

.get(function(req, res) {
  res.status(200).json(Users.getAll());

});` Why does this seem to fail for me? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys, I was able to pass a couple of my tests but I don't understand how sometimes I get a 200 until I add the 201. That seems to overwrite the 200 in my mocha tests.